# Rule for excluding in XML comparison using BeyondCompare

Tags: beyondcompare

I need to add a rule in beyond compare when comparing xml files. I need to ignore nodes that begin with something containing the words `exclude="true"` 
and end with the words `</File>`

```
  <File name="LogData.txt" exclude="true" type="TIMESTAMP">
   <Date>2012-09-27 17:43:36.211</Date>
  </File>
```

I have managed to create a rule for my example instance like this:

Beginning with:   `<File name="LogData.txt" exclude="true"`
Ending with:   `</File>`

But I need something more generic, something that will ignore any File node that contains the exclude="true" attribute.

Answer (score 0):

What was your solution?
Did you try to use regular expressions like this:
[image]

The Text from-expression `<File (.*)exclude="true"` has the `.*`to express *any character so often as possible*

---

Another solution is to use an external conversion.

I wrote e litte ruby-script like this:

```
File.open(ARGV.last, "w"){|f|
  f.write(File.read( ARGV.first).gsub( %r{<(.+?)\s[^>]+exclude="true".*?>(.*?)</\1>}m, ""))
}
```

It takes the first parameter as a source file name and writes a converted xml to the target file.

This script can be used as a conversion tool :

[image]

This comparison:
[image]
becomes
[image]

Instead of the script I was also successfull with the one liner

### ruby -e "File.open('%t', 'w'){|f| f.write(File.read('%s').gsub( /]+exclude=.true..*?>(.*?)</File>/m, ''))}"

If you adapt the script to

```
File.open(ARGV.last, "w"){|f|
  f.write(File.read( ARGV.first).gsub( %r{(<(.+?)\s[^>]+exclude="true".*?>(.*?)</\2>)}m, "<!--\n\\1\n-->"))
}
```

the excluded part is not removed but set into a comment (`<!-- ... -->`) and you get:
[image]

The difference is now an unimportant difference (blue instead red) and you may ignore this difference.

Remarks:
* If you want to use my script you need ruby.
* You may write your conversion script in another language if you want.
* The regular expression I used is not well tested. it may be wrong with nested tags.